# Media queries issue

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to show my webpage on mobile devices similar to desktop version-which I have done it. Here I didn't add viewport tag to my page. Im trying to increase only font-size on mobile devices for that I have written media queries like :

```css
@media (max-width: 576px)
```

or

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 576px)
```

when I resize the browser to 575px font-sizes are changing but when I actually inspect on chrome I don't see media query snippets which I have applied and not on actual mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

This how you should add your media query.
Just change the body to any element / class / id you want.

Comment: I have tried this- still no effective and I don't see media query when i inspect

Answer (score 0):

If the media query is being used, then you should be able to see it in the Chrome devtools under the 'styles' tab.

It will include the query being used and the associated styles. If your browser isn't the right size to use the media query, it will not be visible in the tab. So to see it in the dev tools, in your case, your browser will have to be less than 576px wide. You can also achieve this by toggling the 'device' option, this way you can resize the browser for you page, and keep Chrome at full size.

See images below:

You can see the media query styles being used

[image: You can see the media query styles being used]

This blue icon is the device toggle button

[image: This blue icon is the device toggle button]

Comment: hey, question- To make media queries to work , Do i need to write view port meta tag for sure ?

Comment: No, you don't need a particular meta tag for media queries to work

Comment: okay- what could be the possible reasons that blocking media queries functionality.

Comment: Could you show me some code, or an example site, or what you're expecting to see and what you're actually seeing? Your question says that the font sizes are changing, so it sounds like the media queries are working, so I'm not sure what your question is exactly. I thought you just wanted to see it in the console?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
<!--
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

-->
<style>
body {
  background-color: pink;
   font-size: 2vw;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
     font-size: 2em;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
<p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>

</body>
</html>

Comment: When i inspect and see it on mobile view on chrome -I don't see media queries which I have applied. In above example when it's <=480 it should be green but I don't see it on mobiles

Comment: Your code works and I can see it changing color in the chrome devtools and I can see the media query. You need to make sure you are inspecting the correct element though, are you inspecting the `body`? That's the element that has the media query applied to it